# Converting the argument to Control [ CS1503 ]

Tags: c#

I have a simple alarm project. I made an operation to create as many alarms as desired, but I am having problems while adding to the new form. The logic of the application is, I start a countdown by creating a new form and adding a timer to it.

I am getting the error

> **Compiler Error CS1503**: the best overloaded method match for 'name' has some invalid arguments

```cs
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form frm = new Form();
    frm.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = tiffBoxName + "->CountTime " });
    frm.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "|" });
    frm.Controls.Add(count_down(textBox1.Text));
    frm.Show();
}

internal void count_down(string timeLimit)
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(ReloadSound); 
    int duration = Int32.Parse(timeLimit);
    if (duration == 0)
    {
        countTimer1.Stop();

        player.Play();
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1200);
        Task.Delay(1200);
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (duration > 0)
    {
        duration--;
        labelCount1.Text = duration.ToString();
    }
}
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1502) on this did not help me. what can i do to pass the functions and variables to the new form and run them?

Comment: C does not have `private` and `internal` keywords. Edit your question to tag the question with the correct language you're using.

Comment: I transferred what I saw on the error screen. Which word do you think is the most appropriate?

Comment: It seems like you're programming in C# instead of C. Also, [do not post error messages as images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Yes, I fixed the tag and link.

Comment: Okay, so **what happens** when you tried using this code? **How is that different** from what you expected to happen? If there is an error message, then show the [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error as properly formatted text (formatted like multi-line code), [not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), in the question itself (not the title).

Comment: The display language of the error message is not English. That's why I gave the image and [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503) link.

Comment: You cannot do this: `frm.Controls.Add(count_down(textBox1.Text));`, because the method `count_down` does not have a Control as return type. It has the `void` return type, meaning that it does not return a value.

Comment: I tried to do it but was unsuccessful. I think I'll create a sample form and clone it. Thanks for the information you provided.